# SQL Server Cannot open database requested by the login (via pyodbc). But login works on SSMS

Tags: python, sql-server, database, ssms, pyodbc

Here's my connection string:

```
'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=localhost;Database=myDatabase;UID=admin;PWD=admin;Mars_Connection=Yes'
```

I am able to login to the database using the same login credentials on SSMS. But when I try using the `pyodbc.connect()` I get this error:

> [28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot
> open database "myDatabase" requested by the login. The login failed.

Can someone help me out with this issue?

Comment: The error message suggests that the UID and PWD credentials are correct enough to be able to login to the server, but that they don't have sufficient access to the `myDatabase` database. When your login credentials "work" from SSMS are you actually using the `myDatabase` database and able to execute queries within it?

Comment: Are you connecting to the correct (i.e., default) instance in your code - the same one you connect to using SSMS?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Yes I am using the same credentials to access myDatabase and it works fine on SSMS, not via pyodbc. Plus the same code works on a remote SQL server. But when i try it on my local SQL server instance, it fails to login by uid and pwd